# Ruby sort array with objects by first character of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

this is my first try using ruby, this is probably a simple problem, I have been stuck for an hour now, I have a ruby array with some objects in it, and I want that array to sort by the first character in the objects name property (which I make sure is always a number.)

the names are similar to:

> 4This is an option
>
> 3Another option
>
> 1Another one
>
> 0Another one
>
> 2Second option

I have tried:

```
objectArray.sort_by {|a| a.name[0].to_i}
objectArray.sort {|a,b| a.name[0].to_i <=> b.name.to_i}
```

In both cases my arrays sorting doesnt change.. (also used the destructive version of sort! and sort_by!)

I looped through the array like this:

```
objectArray.each do |test|
  puts test.name[0].to_i  
  puts "\n"
end
```

and sure enough I see the integer value it should have

Comment: `objectArray.sort_by {|a| a[0] }` ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the a object has more properties (name, price, description), so I don't think this will work?

Comment: No I'm expecting objectArray.sort! and objectArray.sort_by! to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort by `name`. Since strings are sorted in [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) order, the objects will be sorted by name's first character :

```
class MyObject
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_s
    "My Object : #{name}"
  end
end

names = ['4This is an option',
         '3Another option',
         '1Another one',
         '0Another one',
         '2Second option']

puts object_array = names.map { |name| MyObject.new(name) }
# My Object : 4This is an option
# My Object : 3Another option
# My Object : 1Another one
# My Object : 0Another one
# My Object : 2Second option

puts object_array.sort_by(&:name)
# My Object : 0Another one
# My Object : 1Another one
# My Object : 2Second option
# My Object : 3Another option
# My Object : 4This is an option
```

If you want, you could also define `MyObject#<=>` and get the correct sorting automatically :

```
class MyObject
  def <=>(other)
    name <=> other.name
  end
end

puts object_array.sort
# My Object : 0Another one
# My Object : 1Another one
# My Object : 2Second option
# My Object : 3Another option
# My Object : 4This is an option
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried with an array like this one:

```
[
  { id: 5, name: "4rge" }, 
  { id: 7, name: "3gerg" }, 
  { id: 0, name: "0rege"}, 
  { id: 2, name: "2regerg"}, 
  { id: 8, name: "1frege"}
]
```

And I don't have any issues with @sagarpandya82's answer:

```
arr.sort_by { |a| a[:name][0] }
# => [{:id=>0, :name=>"0rege"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"1frege"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"2regerg"}, {:id=>7, :name=>"3gerg"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"4rge"}]
```

Comment: But your answer is different from @sugarpandya82? it look similar to my version, should mine normally work? : 

objectArray.sort {|a,b| a.name[0].to_i <=> b.name[0].to_i}

Comment: Yes, and it's not necessary to cast symbols to integers, sorting works fine with symbols and sorts by codes. And if `objectArray` is a `Hash`, a `Structure` or something like that, and `name` method isn't defined on the object, you should get name this way: `a[:name]`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I think the problem was my name was a method inside the object, so I accepted Erics answer, and upvoted yours. Thanks again.